# Open declaration feature in VI

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide, vi

I'm a vi user for coding in Python. I love it: powerful, lowlevel, minimal gui without useless buttons, etc.

Now I'm approaching C++ with an opensource project that—as usual happened in opensource project—has poor documentation and sometimes (well, a lot of times) I have to open declaration and implementation and see what a particular function does.

In Eclipse this is really easy to do due to the Open Declaration (shortcut <kbd>F3</kbd>) feature. But I don't like the CDT plugin for Eclipse. I have a makefile project and it indicates some error in importing external `.cpp` files inside this opensource framework that requires a custom structure for directory and build path (and it's annoying to create a project every time in Eclipse for this custom structure).

I wish to have the same feature in vi. Do you know of anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vim doesn't offer a feature like that by itself. A rudimentary way would be to use `gd` in command mode. If you want more sophisticated support, take a look at ctags and cscope. Those tools offer which you ask for and integrate nicely into Vim. A quick google search brought me to [this link](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html), which explains how to use cscope within Vim. Using ctags quite as easy: generate the ctags database/tags file and use Ctrl+] on an identifier to jump to its declaration. See `:help ctags` for more information.

Comment: ctags will work, but hopefully there's something newer that will analyze code as it's edited.

Comment: run ctags via `cron` or `watch`?

Comment: I prefer using an autocmd which runs ctags when files are saved.

Answer (score 1):

One option: Use QT Creator with FakeVim mode enabled. You can follow declarations with `F2`.

Comment: i just tried it for curiosity. it's graphically very clean and minimal. i like it. but f2 works only for files in the project not in the frameworks that i linked and compile with makefile